# Concatenate three columns data into one column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone tell me which command is used for concatenate three columns data into one column in PostgreSQL database?

e.g.

If the columns are

```
begin | Month | Year
   12 |     1 | 1988
   13 |     3 | 1900
   14 |     4 | 2000
   15 |     5 | 2012
```

result like

```
Begin
12-1-1988 
13-3-1900
14-4-2000
15-5-2012
```

Comment: Have you tried consulting the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) for this very basic question?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to turn these into a single date type value rather than storing as a string? Do you really need a string here?

Answer (score 10):

Just use concatenation operator `||` : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d66bb/2

```
select begin || '-' || month || '-' || year as begin 
from t;
```

Output:

```
|     BEGIN |
-------------
| 12-1-1988 |
| 13-3-1900 |
| 14-4-2000 |
| 15-5-2012 |
```

---

If you want to change the begin column itself, begin column must be of string type first, then do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/13210/2

```
update t set begin = begin || '-' || month || '-' || year ;
```

Output:

```
|     BEGIN |
-------------
| 12-1-1988 |
| 13-3-1900 |
| 14-4-2000 |
| 15-5-2012 |
```

---

**UPDATE**

About this:

> ```
> but m not getting null value column date
> ```

Use this:

```
select (begin || '-' || month || '-' || year)::date as begin 
from t
```

Comment: but m not getting null value column date

Comment: sorry, I can't get what you mean by not getting null value date. if one of the fields has a null, it propagates to the whole expression, hence making the whole result null. Care to elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [9.4. String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I just stumbled upon it.  Doesn't it make more sense to create a date data type?  You can do that using:

```
select make_date(year, month, begin)
```

A date seems more useful than a string (and you can even format it however you like using `to_char()`).